# Changing Hash on Section Change with Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop, hashchange

Something is undefined, and it's not working for me. I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

```
//change the window hash
var changeHash = function(a) {
    document.location.hash = a
};
//get the scrollPos
var scrollPos = function(){
    $(window).scrollTop()
};
//find the position of the top of element
var topPos = function(a){
    $(a).offset().top
};
//find the position of the bottom of element
var bottomPos = function(a){
    $(a).offset().top + $(a).height()
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < bottomPos('#top')) {
        $('.navbar').fadeOut('fast');
        changeHash('');
    }
    else {
        $('.navbar').fadeIn('fast');
        return;

        if(scrollPos <= topPos('#services') && scrollPos >= bottomPos('#services')){
            changeHash('services');
        }
        if(scrollPos <= topPos('#work') && scrollPos >= bottomPos('#work')){
            changeHash('work');
        }
        if(scrollPos <= topPos('#connect') && scrollPos >= bottomPos('#connect')){
            changeHash('connect');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually returning calculated values in 3 of your functions. Try this:

```
//get the scrollPos
var scrollPos = function(){
    return $(window).scrollTop();
};
//find the position of the top of element
var topPos = function(a){
    return $(a).offset().top;
};
//find the position of the bottom of element
var bottomPos = function(a){
    return $(a).offset().top + $(a).height();
};
```

Side Note: You may want to get ride of the `return` in the `window` - `scroll` - `else` statement?